# Reactjs - React Router disallowing paths

Tags: reactjs, path, react-router

I have a route

```
<Route exact path="/view/:personID" component={PersonView} />
```

It works fine, however /view still renders, albeit with no person in it. Is there a way to disallow this path or turn in into a 404?

Answer was to use switch

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/view/:personID" component={PersonView} />
  <Redirect from='/view' to='/' />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Answer:<Switch>
            <Route exact path="/view/:personID" component={PersonView} />
            <Redirect from='/view' to='/' />
 </Switch>

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this on your component, in the `render` section test if you have your `personID` if not return a custom error/view.

Comment: Your answer works I wanted to keep the routes in the same place.